This error occurs when importing the JSON Logger from Exchange into my Anypoint Studio Mule 4
I'm trying to work with the JSON Logger, but when I select it from Exchange in my Anypoint Studio, I get the following error:
An error occurred while downloading the JSON Logger - Mule 4
The following exceptions were encountered while resolving dependency 209ef67a-ae27-4f34-965a-a34fed477013:json-logger:2.1.0:
There was an issue solving the dependencies for the bundleDescriptors:
[[BundleDescriptor{groupId='209ef67a-ae27-4f34-965a-a34fed477013', artifactId='json-logger', baseVersion='null', version='2.1.0', type='jar', classifier=Optional[mule-plugin], systemPath=Optional.empty}]]
I want to be able to import the JSON Logger and use it in my workflow.

Maybe it was incorrectly uploaded to your org's Exchange instance, or the versions you are using are incompatible. Not enough information. Is that the complete error message?
